# the app crashes and the error is in the toolbar in android

Tags: android, android-widget, material-design, android-toolbar, android-logcat

my app crashes whenever it opens , the logcat says it is an error in generating the ToolBar widget but i did it on an old app and it worked , i dont know where the error is please advice what am i missing

MainActivity.java:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Toolbar tb;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //connect the toolbar to the activity//
    tb = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.appbar);
    //tell the app that we will use this toolbar not his own//
    setSupportActionBar(tb);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.igh_eg.bplus.MainActivity">

<include layout="@layout/app_bar" android:id="@+id/appbar"/>
<TextView
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

appbar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@color/primaryColor"
app:theme="@style/mycustomtoolbar"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

the Logcat:

```
09-17 12:10:30.445    3869-3869/com.igh_eg.bplus E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.igh_eg.bplus, PID: 3869
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.igh_eg.bplus/com.igh_eg.bplus.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2350)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:163)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1257)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

Comment: You have to use a theme which support toolbar

Comment: What is your style in your style.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Please check Your Styles.xml in values folder that it is defined or not and in Manifiest also to check applied theme

You can take sample from this

```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="android:displayOptions">disableHome</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: i am using Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar and it worked on another app

Answer (score 0):

Thx guys for your help , i just discovered that the colors.xml file was put in the Values-V22 resource file instead of the normal one and i am actually building on API 19

and so whenever i build the app it does not see the color of the toolbar or anything and crashes :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead giving id at include tag change your both layout like the following

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context="com.igh_eg.bplus.MainActivity">

<include layout="@layout/app_bar" />

<TextView
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**appbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
  android:id="@+id/appbar" 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@color/primaryColor"
  app:theme="@style/mycustomtoolbar"
  app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```